# [Play]Don't use multiple parameters in a route for display a view that takes multiple parameters

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, routes

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application in Scala.

In My application I'm using a form representing an Integer range(start, finish).

The range `class` is written as following:

```
case class Range (
      startDate: Long,
      finishDate: Long)
```

I've defined a form like the following:

```
val rangeForm: Form[Range] = Form (
    mapping(
      "startDate" -> longNumber(min = 0, max = System.currentTimeMillis()),
      "finishDate" -> longNumber(min = 0, max = System.currentTimeMillis())
    )(Range.apply)(Range.unapply)

  )
```

In my `StatisticsController` `class` I've defined three four:

- `calculateStatisticsOnRange(range: Range): Future[(Double, Int)]`: that calculate the number and average of click of the user in a range;
- `getCalculateStatisticsOnRangeForm` that display the form
- `calculateGoodAdvicesHtml` that check if the form has errors
- `displayStatistics(average: Double, count:Int)` that display the result of the search.

My form view is implemented like:

```
@(rangeForm: Form[recommendationsystem.models.Range])

@recommendationsystem.views.html.main("Insert a range")(recommendationsystem.views.html.nav.navbar("statistics")) {
    <h1>Insert here the range</h1>
    <div class="container">
        @helper.form(action = recommendationsystem.controllers.manager.routes.StatisticsController.calculateGoodAdvicesHtml()) {

                <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder = "start"
                                     name="startDate" value="@rangeForm("startDate")" />
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="finish"
                                    name="finishDate" value="@rangeForm("finishDate")" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>



        }
    </div>

}
```

My controller methods are implemented like:

```
def getCalculateStatisticsOnRangeForm = Action {
     Ok(recommendationsystem.views.html.manager.statistics.forms.rangeform(rangeForm))
   }



def calculateGoodAdvicesHtml = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val form = rangeForm.bindFromRequest

    form.fold(
      errors => Future{BadRequest(recommendationsystem.views.html.manager.statistics.forms.rangeform(errors))},
      range =>  {calculateStatisticsOnRange(range) flatMap {result => Future{Redirect(routes.StatisticsController.displayStatistics(result._1, result._2))}}}
    )

  }


def displayStatistics(average: Double, count:Int) = Action{
    Ok(recommendationsystem.views.html.manager.statistics.goodadvise(average, count))
  }
```

In my route file I've the following routes:

```
GET            /statistics/good                        @recommendationsystem.controllers.manager.StatisticsController.getCalculateStatisticsOnRangeForm

POST           /statistics/good                        @recommendationsystem.controllers.manager.StatisticsController.calculateGoodAdvicesHtml

POST           /statistics/good/json                   @recommendationsystem.controllers.manager.StatisticsController.calculateGoodAdvicesJson

GET            /statistics/:average/:count             @recommendationsystem.controllers.manager.StatisticsController.displayStatistics(average: Double, count: Int)
```

I don't like to pass multiple parameters in the route of /statistics/:average/:count, there is an other way to make that?

Comment: So your question is just concerning routes? If so why to put other irrelevant details in your question?

Comment: Yes, my question is about the routes. If It's a problem the code posted I can edit my Post. My problem is that if I have a form with a lot of parameters my routes become too long.

Comment: You don't need long routes for handling forms. Take a look at [Play docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms). You can easily bind your form to your data then.

Comment: I've already read that page of the doc.
But in my case I don't have any Id, I've only some dates that represents query parameters.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You don't need Id. Just use your arbitrary names for field names.